# prevent vim from replacing % with file name

Tags: bash, shell, vim, vimrc

I am messing around with .vimrc and I had this idea to have function like follow:

```
function Fill_line ()
       execute "! printf '=%.0s' {1..10}"
endfunction
```

my output is:

```
Hello =test.cpp.0s
```

I want it to be:

```
==========
```

I have tried this as well:

```
function Fill_line ()
       execute "! printf '=\%.0s' {1..10}"
endfunction
```

My problem is how do I escape `%` character so it does not replace it with file name.
keep in mind this is simplified example of otherwise complex function.

Comment: try with 2 backslashes

Comment: @mosvy put that as an answer pls!!!!! It solved my issue :)

Comment: Well there _is_ an entire Stack Exchange site devoted to vi, and it has had questions like https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9910/ for some time.

Comment: @JdeBP sorry I did not know that there is site and there is an answer. I would not like to delete this question since I gave mosvy upvote and accepted his answer, but if I have to.

Comment: @JdeBP FWIW that vi.stackexchange.com link has no answer for this question. It's simply suggesting to use `\%`, which the OP already did in the 2nd example and which did not work for the reason I've explained in my answer. Find another one.

Comment: I didn't say that it was this exact question, just showed that it had questions in this very vein for some years.  Note that https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/10851/ has better answers than yours.  (-:

Comment: @JdeBP: +1, using `shellescape()` is actually the officially recommended way to do it.

Comment: The question is: What do you want to do? Fill the current line with `=` until a certain column? Underline the current line? If you describe your real goal, you might get a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either use two backslashes or use single quotes:

```
execute "! printf '=\\%.0s' {1..10}"

execute '! printf "=\%.0s" {1..10}'
```

You need that because, when parsing double quoted strings (`"..."`), vim will remove any backslashes that do not start an escape it knows about (eg. `\n` or `\x0a`), so the string being passed to the `execute` command will end up being `! printf '=%.0s' {1..10}`, and the `%` will be replaced with the current file name.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, consider maps. I have this map that underlines the current line:

```
map <Leader>= "ayy"ap:s/./=/g<CR>:nohlsearch<CR>
```

My mapleader is `=`, so I can underline the current line with <kbd>=</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> in normal mode.

Answer (score 0):

As it is unclear what you are trying to do:

1. Fill the current line with `=` up to column 80

   ```
   map _= :execute 'normal A' . repeat("=", (80-col("$")+1))<cr>
   ```
2. Underline the current line:

   ```
   map _= :co.<cr>Vr=
   ```
3. Add a separator (80 chars)

   ```
   map _= :call append(line('.'), repeat("=", 80))<cr>
   ```

Comment: My problem was escaping `%`, I do already have something like this in place. My code in original post is extremely simplified.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already correctly answered, the `%` needs to be escaped so that Vim doesn't replace it with the current filename (as per [`:help cmdline-special`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#cmdline-special)), and inside a double-quoted string the backslash needs to be doubled.

However, Vim offers a [`:help shellescape()`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#shellescape%28%29) function that does the work for you (and considers *all* special characters!):

```
execute "! printf " . shellescape("=%.0s",1) . " {1..10}"
```

Here, you need to *escape each argument separately*; for the bare `printf` this isn't necessary, and the `{1..10}` must not be quoted in the shell to get expanded.

Note that there's no need to shell out solely for `printf`; Vim has [`printf()`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#printf%28%29) built-in.

Comment: *% needs to be escaped so that Vim doesn't replace it* I knew this, but I did not know how :). I wish I could select both of these answers. Since @mosvy works as well in given situation.